# Migration to ESLint

Tags: angular

I want to migrate my angular app to ESLint instead of TSLint because of two reasons:

- TSLint's indent is not working. https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/2814;
- TSLint is deprecated.

I don't seem to find any tutorial for angular. Is there someone who did that? I can use ESLint but what about all TSLint remaining files/settings?

I just want the indent option to be working, somehow.

```
"indent": {
  "options": ["spaces", 2]
}
```

Any recommendations? What do you guys use?

Comment: What editor you are using ?

Comment: VS Code. I was looking at https://medium.com/@victormejia/setting-up-prettier-in-an-angular-cli-project-2f50c3b9a537 earlier but I remember when I tried it for first time, the settings were messed up. If there is a way to remove TSLint and put ESLint instead, it would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently migrating my angular app to eslint. I extend the eslint configuration by adding the packages [@typescript-eslint/parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser) and the [@†ypescript-eslint/eslint-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin). Currently I am still setting up the whole eslint configuration but I hope these two links already helped you.

For the indent I added:

```
"@typescript-eslint/indent": ["error", 4]
```

to the `rules` object.

Answer (score -1):

Try This https://stackoverflow.com/a/65552444/14764759
tslint-to-eslint-config

Code Style: Prettier Coverage: 100% TypeScript: Strict NPM version Circle CI Join the chat at https://gitter.im/tslint-to-eslint-config/community Code Style: Prettier

Converts your TSLint configuration to the closest reasonable ESLint equivalent.

TSLint is deprecated. Use tslint-to-eslint-config to expedite migrating your project onto ESLint.

Consider taking a peek at the relevant documentation:

```
ESLint itself
typescript-eslint, which allows TypeScript files to be linted by ESLint
```

Usage

npx tslint-to-eslint-config

The tslint-to-eslint-config command reads in any existing linter, TypeScript, and package configuration files, then creates an .eslintrc.js result based on them.

For any TSLint rules with corresponding ESLint equivalents, those equivalents will be used in the new configuration. TSLint rules without ESLint equivalents will be wrapped with eslint-plugin-tslint.

```
Requires Node 10+ (LTS) and TSLint 5.18+
```

FAQs

We strongly advise reading docs/FAQs.md before planning your conversion from TSLint to ESLint.
CLI Flags

Each of these flags is optional:

```
comments: TypeScript configuration or file glob path(s) to convert TSLint rule flags to ESLint within.
config: Path to print the generated ESLint configuration file to.
editor: Path to an editor configuration file to convert linter settings within.
eslint: Path to an ESLint configuration file to read settings from.
package: Path to a package.json file to read dependencies from.
prettier: Add eslint-config-prettier to the plugins list.
tslint: Path to a TSLint configuration file to read settings from.
typescript: Path to a TypeScript configuration file to read TypeScript compiler options from.
```

comments

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --comments

Default: none

Indicates to convert from TSLint rule flags to ESLint inline comments. Comments such as // tslint:disable: tslint-rule-name will be converted to equivalents like // eslint-disable eslint-rule-name.

If passed without arguments, respects the excludes, files, and includes in your TypeScript configuration.

If passed a single file path ending with .json, that is treated as a TypeScript configuration file describing with files to convert.

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --comments tsconfig.json

If passed any other arguments, those are treated as glob paths for file paths to convert:

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --comments 'src/**/*.ts'

config

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --config .eslintrc.json

Default: .eslintrc.js

Path to print the generated ESLint configuration file to.

The file extension of this path will be used to determine the format of the created file:

```
.js file paths will be written module.exports = ... JavaScript
Other file paths will default to JSON
```

editor

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --editor ./path/to/.vscode/settings.json

Default: .vscode/settings.json

Path to an editor configuration file to convert settings settings within. Any VS Code style editor settings for TSLint will be converted to their ESLint equivalents.
eslint

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --eslint ./path/to/eslintrc.js

Default: --config's value

Path to an ESLint configuration file to read settings from. The generated ESLint configuration file will include any settings imported from this file.
package

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --package ./path/to/package.json

Default: package.json

Path to a package.json file to read dependencies from. This will help inform the generated ESLint configuration file's env settings.
prettier

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --prettier

Default: false

Add eslint-config-prettier to the list of ESLint plugins. We highly recommend you use Prettier for code formatting.

When --prettier isn't enabled:

```
If the output configuration already doesn't enable any formatting rules, it'll extend from eslint-config-prettier.
Otherwise, a CLI message will suggest running with --prettier.
```

tslint

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --tslint ./path/to/tslint.json

Default: tslint.json

Path to a TSLint configuration file to read settings from. This file is piped into TSLint's --print-config to generate the list of rules to enable in the generated ESLint configuration file.
typescript

npx tslint-to-eslint-config --typescript ./path/to/tsconfig.json

Default: tsconfig.json

Path to a TypeScript configuration file to read TypeScript compiler options from. This will help inform the generated ESLint configuration file's env settings.
Node API

You can use tslint-to-eslint-config programmatically via its exported functions. See docs/API for details.

import { convertLintConfig } from "tslint-to-eslint-config";

const result = await convertLintConfig();

Development

See the general development docs.